# How to pass data from Action to Ajax success function in mvc4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am want to when login succesfully then call my success function otherwise call error function

View code here

```
<div class="container">
<div class="login-container">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/download.jpeg")" style="max-width:95%;" /></div>
    <div class="form-box">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { @class = "form-control", @id="userid", @placeholder = "Username", @required = "required", @maxlength = "20" })
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "userpass", @placeholder = "Password", @required = "required", @maxlength = "20" })
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" id="login-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</button>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

ajax code here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-btn').click(function () {
        var dataObject = {
            Id: $("#userid").val(),
            Password: $("#userpass").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Login","Account")',
            type: "POST",
            data: dataObject,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.toString() == "login") {
                    toastr['success']("Login Successfully");
                }
                else if (data.toString() == "error") {
                    toastr['error']("Id or Password is incorrect");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                toastr['error']("Hello");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Controller Code here:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginMaster model)
    {
        string message = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = from emp in db.LoginMasters
                           where emp.UserId == model.UserId && emp.Password == model.Password
                           select emp;

                var rol = user.FirstOrDefault();
                if (rol != null)
                {
                    var realrol = rol.Role;
                    if (realrol == "admin")
                    {
                        message = "login";
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else if (realrol == "user")
                    {
                        Session["userid"] = rol.UserId;
                        message = "login";
                        return RedirectToAction("User", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "error";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.cath = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            message = "error";
        }
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

        return View();
```

i am want to when we login succesfully that time call this

```
toastr['success']("Login Successfully");
```

and when login fail that time call

```
toastr['error']("Id or Password is incorrect");
```

please solve this problem.
thanks in advance!

Comment: it is not working for you? whats problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your controller code hits the part that returns the json then you can access it via `.Data`:

```
success: function (data) {

            if (data.Data == "login") {
                toastr['success']("Login Successfully");
            }
            else if (data.Data == "error") {
                toastr['error']("Id or Password is incorrect");
            }
        }
```

You set the `.Data` property within your code here:

```
new JsonResult { Data = message ...
```

and the problem with your success call is that it is testing the entire json object, *not* the `.Data` property.

```
data.toString() == "login"
```

Comment: no sir our problem is our Action where we can put hit point that is not run in a sequence our this point is firstly execute

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
then after execute this other part 
so problem is we can not set correct string in message variable so please first of all you can make a sample in js fiddle then provide me link

Answer (score 0):

no sir our problem is our Action where we can put hit point that is not run in a sequence our this point is firstly execute

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

then after execute this part

```
try
        {
            var user = from emp in db.LoginMasters
                       where emp.UserId == model.UserId && emp.Password == model.Password
                       select emp;

            var rol = user.FirstOrDefault();
            if (rol != null)
            {
                var realrol = rol.Role;
                if (realrol == "admin")
                {
                    message = "login";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else if (realrol == "user")
                {
                    Session["userid"] = rol.UserId;
                    message = "login";
                    return RedirectToAction("User", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "error";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.cath = ex.Message;
        }
```

so problem is we can not set correct string in message variable so please first of all you can make a sample in js fiddle then provide me link

Answer (score 0):

As you have used this code in your script. :

```
var dataObject = {
            Id: $("#userid").val(),
            Password: $("#userpass").val()
        };
```

if your `LoginMaster` model contains `Id` & `Password` it'll display data.
If you have `UserId` & `Password` then you have to change your code in script like below.

```
 var dataObject = {
                UserId: $("#userid").val(),
                Password: $("#userpass").val()
            };
```

In short replace `Id` with `UserId`.